# Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

Tags: c#, text-files, textwriter

I am trying to write text to my txt file. After the first write the application crash with error

> Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

My list contains links that the browser opens and I want to save all of them in txt file (like a log).

My code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
                    "c:\\linksLog.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

for (int i = 0; i < linksList.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(browserType, linksList[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    using (sw)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(linksList[i]);
        sw.Close();
    }

    Thread.Sleep((int)delayTime);

    if (!cbNewtab.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (process.ProcessName == getProcesses)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't close the StreamWriter (sw) until you are done using it.

Comment: use "using" for streams to dispose of the stream properly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're in a `for` loop, but you close and dispose of your `StreamWriter` on the first iteration:

```
using (sw)
{
    sw.WriteLine(linksList[i]);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Instead, remove that block, and wrap everything in one `using` block:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\linksLog.txt", true)) {
    foreach (var link in linksList) {
        try {
            Process.Start(browserType, list);                        
        } catch (Exception) {}

        sw.WriteLine(link);

        Thread.Sleep((int)delayTime);

        if (!cbNewtab.Checked) {
            var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(getProcesses);

            foreach (var process in processes) {
                try {
                    process.Kill();
                } catch (Exception) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are closing you Stream in the loop, should done only after...

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\linksLog.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

    for (int i = 0; i < linksList.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(browserType, linksList[i]);                        
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        // Removed the using blocks that closes the stream and placed at the end of loop
        sw.WriteLine(linksList[i]);

        Thread.Sleep((int)delayTime);

        if (!cbNewtab.Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (process.ProcessName == getProcesses)
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
    }

    sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
using (sw)
```

closes/disposes your `StreamWriter`.

Since you are looping, you dispose an already disposed `StreamWriter`.

Better to close the `StreamWriter` *outside* the loop, after all write operations are finished.

In addition, catching exceptions and ignoring the caught exception is almost always a bad idea. If you can't handle an exception, do not catch it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are, indeed, closing your stream in the middle of the loop. You have the `using (sw)` block in the middle, which will work fine in the first run through the `for` loop, and then crash. To fix it, just drop the `sw.Close()` call, and move the `using` to be outside the `for` loop:

Comment: but what if the app crash in the middle ?

Comment: You can call `sw.Flush()` if you want the data to be written to disk in every iteration, though in general, the `using` call translates to a `try {} catch {} finally { sw.Dispose();}` call, so even if you throw an exception, the stream is closed properly.

Comment: if i want to use using, i need to write close() ? where to put using in my code ?

Comment: You don't need to call `Close()` explicitly. The `using` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont write the `sw.Close()` in your code because if the file is closed the code cannot read the file.

Comment: there is way that i can ongoing see all my link in the file ? i mean in the middle of the process while i am still in the for statement